# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer from AVCaptureSession stops video stream randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I created a simple AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer based on a AVCaptureSession and added the layer to a UIView.

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;

[self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

[session startRunning];
```

After running the app, the code seems to work fine - but after a while (about 60. - 90. seconds) the video is freezing randomly!

I added a button to stop and start the AVCaptureSession agin and if I press the button after freezing, the video starts working again...

Does anybody know a reason for the randomly stopping video stream?

Answer (score 4):

Try to **set maxRecordedDuration for AVCaptureMovieFileOutput** and **add** that **in your AVCaptureSession**, here is the sample code for 5000 second record duration

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *MovieFileOutput; =[[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

Float64 MaxRecordDuration = 5000;           //Maximum RecordDuration in seconds replace 5000 with YOUR_MAX_DURATION
int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;    //Frames per second
CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(MaxRecordDuration, preferredTimeScale);    //<<SET MAX DURATION

MovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
MovieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;                        
if ([session canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput])
{
    [session addOutput:MovieFileOutput];
}
[session commitConfiguration];
[session startRunning];
```